# How to specify date format when using pandas.to_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, datetime-format, date-formatting

The default output format of `to_csv()` is:

```
12/14/2012  12:00:00 AM
```

I cannot figure out how to output only the date part with specific format:

```
20121214
```

or date and time in two separate columns in the csv file:

```
20121214,  084530
```

The documentation is too brief to give me any clue as to how to do these. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to save these as separate columns:

```
df['date'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d%m%Y'))
df['time'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H%M%S'))
```

and then be specific about which columns to export to csv:

```
df[['date', 'time', ... ]].to_csv('df.csv')
```

Answer (score 174):

Since version [v0.13.0 (January 3, 2014)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.13.0.html?highlight=date_format) of Pandas you can use the `date_format` parameter of the [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method:

```
df.to_csv(filename, date_format='%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: yes but is there a way to store two different Timestamp columns using different formats?  I could convert them to string first, then save, but is there something more elegant?

Comment: upvoted! if I use %s for date_format i have no idea why the timestamp goes 5 hours 30 mins behind the datetime values, my datetime values in the dataframe are already at UTC, how do I convert 2018-06-28 12:15:00+00:00 to unix epoch while writing to csv

Comment: didn't work for me.  i am trying to save this '%Y-%m-%d'. Wwhen I go open up a file, this is saved as %Y/%m%d.

Comment: @PierreD consider `styler` and `to_string` per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76411568/21115)

Comment: I got stuck on this, but it turns out that this will not work on dates, but on datetimes!. So, just convert them to datetime and then the date_format will work.

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) clearly states that date_format is used to "Format string for datetime objects."

Answer (score 9):

To export as a timestamp, do this:

```
df.to_csv(filename, date_format='%s')
```

The `%s` format is [not documented in python/pandas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) but works in this case.

I found the `%s` from [the dates formats of ruby](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime). [Strftime doc for C here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)

Note that the timestamp miliseconds format `%Q` does not work with pandas (you'll have a litteral `%Q` in the field instead of the date). I caried my sets with python 3.6 and pandas 0.24.1

Comment: To also export milliseconds or more precisely microseconds use `%f` like this `df.to_csv(filename, date_format='%s.%f')`