# Pandas to_csv -- date formatting other than 2 digits

Tags: python, date

There is a widely-quoted method in the following answer for specifying date format when using pandas to_csv:

[How to specify date format when using pandas.to_csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999850/how-to-specify-date-format-when-using-pandas-to-csv)

This answer describes:

```
 date_format='%Y%m%d'
```

But I have a different requirement for which  can find no information.

How can I specify a different date format for the actual year/month/day tokens?

...date_format='%Y%m%d'... translates to 2014/10/2 as of today's date. I can use this information to juggle the same data around -- eg 10/2/2014, but I cannot change the format itself.

I would like to output 02-Oct_2014. I tried  '%dd%mmm%yyyy' but the extra letters are just added as extra letters -- no change in the date format.

Is it possible to specify formats other than permutations of '%Y%m%d'?

Comment: Your date format string looks wrong, with three m's. Month abbreviations are %b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas uses `strftime`, so use [the format codes it specifies](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

For `02-Oct_2014` it looks like you want `%d-%b_%Y`

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(5)), index=pd.date_range('10/1/14', periods=5))
>>> print(df.to_csv(date_format='%d-%b_%Y'))
,0
01-Oct_2014,0
02-Oct_2014,1
03-Oct_2014,2
04-Oct_2014,3
05-Oct_2014,4
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the help, it works exactly as required.

Answer (score 1):

The format you want is `'%d-%b_%Y'`.  How did I figure this out?  I looked at [man strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) because that's what is being used under the hood (or an emulation of it).  I searched the docs for "month" and found this:

```
 %b    is replaced by national representation of the abbreviated month name.
```

It's also shown in the Python docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime

And finally, you can test many such formats directly on the *nix command line like so:

```
date +%d-%b_%Y
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the help, it works fine. As you both posted pretty much the same answer and explanation, I accepted the first one to arrive. I hope that's fair.