# How to specify date format when using pandas.to_csv to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: python, date, pandas

The OP of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999850/how-to-specify-date-format-when-using-pandas-to-csv) highlighted the lack of documentation for using the date_format argument in pandas. I would like to format the data into YYYY-MM-DD, not MM/DD/YYYY when using the to_csv command.

I've tried: `frame.to_csv(output_dir, index=False, encoding='utf-8', date_format='%Y-%m-%d')` and it is not working, where frame is a DataFrame

The file I'm trying to convert can be found [here](http://www.filedropper.com/job0104)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already supported in [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) as a param `date_format`:

```
t="""date,val
12/05/1984,sadas
1/11/1980,sadas
2/4/1945,sadas
22/10/1921,sadas"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=[0])
df.to_csv(r'c:\data\date.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Yields:

```
,date,val
0,1984-12-05,sadas
1,1980-01-11,sadas
2,1945-02-04,sadas
3,1921-10-22,sadas
```

The format strings are of the form taken from [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: I had tried that and unfortunately it's not working (%Y-%m-%d)

Comment: What version pandas are you using? this works fine in `0.16.0`

Comment: Are your dates already datetime dtype already or not? post the output from `df.info()`

Comment: Well the only explanation is that they are strings and not datetime, try converting first: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Comment: When I use df.info(), I see that even the columns that are seen as datetime64[ns] are NOT converted to the desired format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77838/discussion-between-jsc123-and-edchum).

Comment: Well you'll need to post raw input data (or a link to your data) and complete code to reproduce this error

Comment: You'll see it in the chat

Comment: very helpful, but how do you know this because it surely isn't mentioned in the documentation for `to_csv`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard datetime string formatting behavior, here that would be:
df.to_csv('df.csv, date_format="%Y-%m-%d")
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

EDIT: don't iterate through the dataframe with strftime, that's highly unoptimized and theres already a built-in function for performing the operation you want

Comment: I had tried that and unfortunately it's not working (%Y-%m-%d)

Comment: That's because it's ("%Y-%m-%d") not (%Y-%m-%d)

Comment: frame.to_csv(output_dir, index=False, encoding='utf-8', date_format="%Y-%m-%d") doesn't work

Comment: I just confirmed that that works. How are you opening the csv afterwards? If you try looking at a csv in excel or similar the dates will be displayed differently, make sure you're verifying in a text editor.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that! Do you have any idea why the "Paid" column isn't datetime64? Should I manually change this?

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Looking at the file in excel, excel automatically converts dates to its format. Looking in notepad the format is what you specify.

Answer (score 0):

You show iterate csv' rows and get every [date](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and format it with strptime method from datetime.