# python - pandas dataframe error when export style object to csv

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe that is formatted differently for each column. I need to export it to csv or dat files. But got the following error message:

AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

How to solve this issue?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def time_formatter(data):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(data, "%Y/%m/%d").date().strftime('%Y%m%d')

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':['2017/01/01', '2017/01/02','2016/12/31'], 'c':['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 'd':[4,5,6]})

formatter = {'a':'{:4.2f}', 'b': time_formatter, 'd':'{:8.2f}'}

df = df.style.format(formatter)

df.to_csv('aaa.csv')
```

Comment: The code you've included runs without error. Can you please include the part of your code that is throwing the error? But the issue is almost certainly that you're calling `to_csv` on a `Styler` object instead of a `DataFrame`.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Can you post the full traceback? This again runs on my system without error (and outputs aaa.csv)

Comment: I forgot to add "df = df.style.format(formatter)". The reason why you had no error was the df has not been altered. Now the df is a Styler object, and when exporting to csv it will give us error. Can you try again?

Comment: So, I believe the issue is that you're overwriting your data frame, as the style application should be inplace. However, I'm not sure pandas styles work with anything except the HTML representation.

Comment: @AlexAlifimoff you are right. That's the same thing that I got so far regarding pandas styler objects. Not sure if there is a way to solve this issue.

Comment: @AlexAlifimoff It looks like the openpyxl engine can do the work: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html

Comment: The other option would be to just change the columns to strings (formatted as you desire) and then export to CSV.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it is because CSV is a plain text format and these files don't contain styling (formatting) information. That's why you are getting `AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`. You need to save it as  an [excel file](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_excel.html) to use different stylings.

Answer (score 1):

I also face same problem and it solved by flowing this
At first import

```
pip install openpyxl
```

then save your file as

```
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not using `to_csv`, but what you want:

```py
from pathlib import Path

s = df.style.hide(axis='index').format(formatter)

path = Path('aaa.csv')
path.write_text(','.join(df.columns))
path.write_text(s.to_string(delimiter=','))
```

Please  / comment [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9448#issuecomment-1577879552) to get `to_csv` on `styler`.