# Keeping the detatime type when using to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I'm relatively new to python and in need of your help.
I have a long DataFrame in which one column is a succession of dates. I used a pd.datetime function to translate all this column to a datetime format, as it is easier to sort them by date.
I want to save this DataFrame, transformed and sorted to gain some time on the future data processing.
Do you have an idea on how I should manage that issue ?
My code so far is this :

```
import pandas as pd


df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.DATE)     
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['NAME', 'DATE']) 
df1.to_csv('df1_sorted.csv')
```

Comment: refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999850/how-to-specify-date-format-when-using-pandas-to-csv)

Comment: Hello, my problem is when I read the csv file I just saved with pd.read_csv, the type of my DATE column has been changed from "pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp" to "str"

Comment: you can make use of the `parse_dates` argument in pandas.read_csv (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), ie `pd.read_csv('filename.csv',parse_dates =['date_column_name'] )`